# Delete the XML files when it's >N files count for each set of files name

Tags: shell-script

In a directory, I would like to delete the files based on the appended date at the end of the file, these files are XML back files. The files should be deleted based on the below criteria.

In each set, if it contains files count more than 12 (per particular set of backup files in their name) then delete the old files, latest files should remain in the same directory.

#### Examples

*Set 1:*

```
Wf_ABCDEF_HGD_AFFGF_DFDF_201601011224.XML
```

**NOTE:** The above file in set 1 should not delete.

*Set 2:*

```
Wf_ABHGD_AFFGF_DFDF_201101211221.XML   
Wf_ABHGD_AFFGF_DFDF_201202211222.XML   
Wf_ABHGD_AFFGF_DFDF_201304411223.XML   
Wf_ABHGD_AFFGF_DFDF_201406611224.XML   
Wf_ABHGD_AFFGF_DFDF_201508811225.XML   
Wf_ABHGD_AFFGF_DFDF_201609911226.XML   
Wf_ABHGD_AFFGF_DFDF_201707711227.XML   
Wf_ABHGD_AFFGF_DFDF_201801081228.XML   
Wf_ABHGD_AFFGF_DFDF_201901911229.XML   
Wf_ABHGD_AFFGF_DFDF_202001811210.XML   
Wf_ABHGD_AFFGF_DFDF_202101511211.XML   
Wf_ABHGD_AFFGF_DFDF_202201811212.XML   
Wf_ABHGD_AFFGF_DFDF_202301811213.XML   
Wf_ABHGD_AFFGF_DFDF_202401911214.XML   
Wf_ABHGD_AFFGF_DFDF_202501041215.XML   
Wf_ABHGD_AFFGF_DFDF_202601031216.XML
```

The below files should be deleted as these are old files based on the file append date.

```
Wf_ABHGD_AFFGF_DFDF_201101211221.XML
Wf_ABHGD_AFFGF_DFDF_201202211222.XML
Wf_ABHGD_AFFGF_DFDF_201304411223.XML
Wf_ABHGD_AFFGF_DFDF_201406611224.XML
```

*Set 3:-*

```
Wf_ABCDEFGHIJKLMONM_201101211221.XML   
Wf_ABCDEFGHIJKLMONM_201202211222.XML   
Wf_ABCDEFGHIJKLMONM_201304411223.XML
Wf_ABCDEFGHIJKLMONM_201406611224.XML   
Wf_ABCDEFGHIJKLMONM_201508811225.XML   
Wf_ABCDEFGHIJKLMONM_201609911226.XML   
Wf_ABCDEFGHIJKLMONM_201707711227.XML   
Wf_ABCDEFGHIJKLMONM_201801081228.XML   
Wf_ABCDEFGHIJKLMONM_201901911229.XML   
Wf_ABCDEFGHIJKLMONM_202001811210.XML   
Wf_ABCDEFGHIJKLMONM_202101511211.XML
```

The above files should not be deleted as this set is equal to or below 12 files.

Comment: Well your points 1 and 3 in the Question are nothing but the same . Because `count < 12`  Is the super set of `count = 1 `.. isn't it?

Comment: if it is less then 12 then it should not delete

Comment: That's what,  the logic checking less than 12 also covers the other point. You need not have a separate logic checking if the file count is 1 since `1 < 12`.  File count be 1 or anything. Until its less than 12 , `count < 12` logic should be sufficient! What say you?

Comment: In one set, if it has only 1 record then it should not delete if it is more than 12 in the set it should delete the old date files. I guess we can achieve by using count, do you have a script based on the above file structure and scenario?

Comment: As told by @saisasanka scenario 1 and 3, look same.

Comment: I only see one criteria, and have edited your question accordingly, if this edit caused your question unclear or it's not what you want, then please do [edit] and clarify.

Comment: followup of previous question https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/462808/72456

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `find` and [Bash Offset Expansion *`${parameter:offset:length}`*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), you could do:

```
find -type f -execdir bash -c 'printf "%s\n" "${@:1:${#@}-12}" ' _ {} +
./Wf_ABHGD_AFFGF_DFDF_201101211221.XML
./Wf_ABHGD_AFFGF_DFDF_201202211222.XML
./Wf_ABHGD_AFFGF_DFDF_201304411223.XML
./Wf_ABHGD_AFFGF_DFDF_201406611224.XML
```

The `${#@}` is returning the total number of files (or arguments in mean).

repeat above for every set of files you have by specifying the pattern in `-name` option of find command above.

Or to get patterns by script:

```
# !/bin/bash

allFILEs=(*.XML)
PATTERNs=$(printf "%s\n" "${allFILEs[@]%_*}" |sort -u)

for pattern in ${PATTERNs[@]};
do
    find -type f -name "*${pattern}*" -execdir bash -c '
        printf "%s\n" "${@:1:${#@}-12}"' _ {} + 2>/dev/null;
done
```

change `printf` with `rm` (in `find ...` command) when you had test and see which files(s) being deleting.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do all scenario :

All 3 of your Scenario has fallen on only one condition, we need to delete the oldest files if the backup file count is greater than 12

```
cd /path/to/dir
FilePattern=(`ls --format single-column *.XML | rev | cut -d '_' -f2-  | rev | sort -u`)

for FILE in ${FilePattern[@]}
do
    File_count=`ls "$FILE"_*.XML | wc -w`
    if [ $File_count -gt 12 ]; then
        REMOVE_count=`expr $File_count - 12`
        ls --format single-column "$FILE"_*.XML | head -n $REMOVE_count |  xargs rm -f
    fi
done
```

- `File_count` will get the number of files avail in the directory
- `if` the removal process starts only if file count is greater than 12.
- `REMOVE_count` calculate the count of files greater than 12
- `ls --format single-column` will list files in a single column in ascending order.
- `head` to get the oldest files
- `rm` to remove

Comment: Siva@ Thanks for your script, I have tried above script but it is getting delete the.XML files which fall under less than 12 also, I need to keep if less than 12 XML files.

Comment: @surajreddy2 I hope u missed double quotes around $FILE